# Adding border in specifics points in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, point

I would like to add a border only for the level 1 of the colunmn 'exot'. I've look for in a lot of sites, but I found only explanations of how to border in general (pch and etc.). The figure 1 is an example (made in photoshop) of how I would like to have the border in my figure.

Thanks for any help right away

```
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)

p<- ggplot(Dataset, aes(sp,log(num))) 
p + geom_point(aes(colour=recal, size = pf))+
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4,10)) +
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))

sp  num recal   pf  exot
A   47  2   7   0
B 22    0   3   0
C   5   0   0   0
D   4   0   0   0
E   2   0   0   0
F   2   0   0   0
G   2   0   0   1
H   2   0   0   0
I   1   0   1   0
J   1   0   0   0
L 1 5   0   0
M   1   0   0   0
N   1   0   0   0
O   1   0   0   0
P   1   0   0   0
Q   1   0   0   0
R   1   0   0   0
S   1   0   0   1
T   1   0   0   1
U   1   0   0   1
```

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that can get you closer would be to use `shape=21` for the points and set the color to `exot` (notice that now the color refers to the border).

Use `scale_manual` to set values to `"white"` and `"red"` then remove the legend:

```
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset, aes(sp,log(num))) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=recal, size = pf, color=as.factor(exot)), shape = 21, stroke = 2)+
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4,10)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("white", "red")) + # set the border to the bg color
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  guides(color = FALSE) + # remove the legend for the border
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

[image]

---

If you still want to use "full" points for the legend of `"pf"` use this:

```
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset, aes(sp,log(num))) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=recal, size = pf, color=as.factor(exot)), shape = 21, stroke = 2)+
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  # change guide for the size 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(4,10), guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=19))) + 
                                         # ^this part (forces the shape to 19)
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("white", "red")) + # set the border to the bg color
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  guides(color = FALSE) + # remove the legend for the border
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Data:

```
tt <- "sp  num recal   pf  exot
A   47  2   7   0
B 22    0   3   0
C   5   0   0   0
D   4   0   0   0
E   2   0   0   0
F   2   0   0   0
G   2   0   0   1
H   2   0   0   0
I   1   0   1   0
J   1   0   0   0
L 1 5   0   0
M   1   0   0   0
N   1   0   0   0
O   1   0   0   0
P   1   0   0   0
Q   1   0   0   0
R   1   0   0   0
S   1   0   0   1
T   1   0   0   1
U   1   0   0   1"

dataset <- read.table(text=tt, header=T)
```

Comment: Hi @Rlave thank you, I had tried in different ways with the shape = 21, but not with color = as.factor (exot). Thank you very much for the two examples, they helped me a lot even in a script of other plot.